# Не обновляется SQL таблица в SQLite3 python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

> Я задаю этот вопрос второй раз, потому что в прошлый раз я неправильно всё объяснил.

У меня есть код:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('data.sql')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data (user_name varchar(20),form_name varchar(35),field_x int,field_y int,form_field varchar)')


def update(user_name,form_name,field_x,field_y,form_field):
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO data(user_name,form_name,field_x,field_y,form_field) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?);',(user_name,form_name,field_x,field_y,form_field))
    conn.commit()


def stop():
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
    print('Соединение прервано')
    

stop()
```

После запуска этого кода создаётся файл data.sql

Потом я вызываю функцию update в коде:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('data.sql')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data (user_name varchar(20),form_name varchar(35),field_x int,field_y int,form_field varchar)')


def update(user_name,form_name,field_x,field_y,form_field):
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO data(user_name,form_name,field_x,field_y,form_field) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?);',(user_name,form_name,field_x,field_y,form_field))
    conn.commit()


def stop():
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
    print('Соединение прервано')
    
#Здесь
update('Вася','хз',3,3,'qwerty')

stop()
```

И запускаю его во второй раз.
Но почему-то таблица не обновляется. Где ошибка?

> И да, файл точно тот, так как он автоматически создаётся при первом запуске кода

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Это был мой вопрос, где я неправильно всё объяснил

Comment: Значит надо было его исправить, а не дубликаты плодить